# React this props get empty object issue

Tags: reactjs, url-routing

React js with the inner component in render method, I put console log this.props getting an empty object value! Here my code,

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute, hashHistory, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

import Home from './home';
import About from './about';


class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
        <div>
            Hi
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App
```

Comment: What are trying to pass?

Comment: I need to get location by props.

Comment: Which version of react-router are you using?

Comment: "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-router": "^4.0.0",

Answer (score 0):

You can use `withRouter` high order component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute, hashHistory, browserHistory, withRouter } from 'react-router';

import Home from './home';
import About from './about';


class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
        <div>
            Hi
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(App)
```

[More info here.](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v4/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md)